# Prove there exists a $P$ such that $\nabla P = F$ iff $(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x})_y = (\frac{\partial F}{\partial y})_x$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Let $F: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, X: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, Y: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be smooth functions such that $$f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}X(x,y) \\ Y(x,y) \end{bmatrix}.$$  Show that there exists $P: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $\nabla P = F$ iff $X_y = Y_x$.

*Notation*: $X_x$ *means* $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}$.

My proof is below, to which I request verification, critique, and suggests, on the proof and exposition.  Is it correct, rigorous, and clear? How can the exposition be improved?

*Note: Proofs are available; this question is to verify or critique **this** proof.*

---

**Proof:**
Let $A: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function such that $A_x = X$.  Such a function must exist since $X$ is assumed smooth.  Then $$A_{yx} = A_{xy} = X_y = Y_x.$$  Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives $$Y(x,y) = A_y(x,y) + \beta(y)$$ for some continuous function $\beta: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.  There exists a function $B: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $B' = \beta$.

Let $$P(x,y) = A(x,y) + B(y).$$  Then $P_x = A_x = X$ and $P_y = A_y + \beta = Y$, giving $\nabla P = F$.  The converse follows directly from Clairaut's Theorem.

Furthermore, it easily follows that for any function $Q, \nabla Q = F$ iff $Q = P + C$ for some $C \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Looks correct. $\phantom{\text{that's all that there is to say}}$